# Change date language

Tags: php, wordpress, date

On WordPress, I created a custom meta field for input dates.

But I need return the dates in my current language. I try to use `setlocale` with no effect:

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "de_DE");
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$date = strtotime( get_user_meta($user_ID, 'subscription', true)); // return 1434499200
$inscricao = date("F Y", $date); // return June 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

> Format the time and/or date according to locale settings. Month and
>   weekday names and other language-dependent strings respect the current
>   locale set with setlocale().

For example:

```
$inscricao = strftime("%B %Y", $date);
```

Comment: I made the change, but it returned F Y.

Comment: Sorry your format is for `date` and not for `strftime`, and I just blindly copied it. Updated my response

Comment: Now it returned  January 1970

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: version 5.5 (wamp) on windows 8.1.

Comment: You might want to lookup the locale string for your windows here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
echo esc_html_e( date_i18n( 'F \d\e Y'  , strtotime( get_user_meta($user_ID, 'subscription', true) ) ) );
```